# Integer constrained optimization with objective function expressed to execute another program call

Tags: gekko

I'm working on an integer optimization problem and would like to try the GEKKO.

Problem Description :
x1,x2,x3,...,x9,x10,x11 (which are integers in the range 1-16) are the eleven integer parameters of an objective function. I would like to find a set of x values to minimize the output of the objective function. However, the objective value is obtained by running another C/C++ program since the problem cannot be expressed in math. formula like your examples.

I suspect if the return value j of the objective function doesn't match the spec. Is j python float OK in the case ? But from the log and double check, the objective value of the init state is 0.06 which is correct. I don't know why it only runs for one iteration and then stop.

```
def f_per_particle(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11):
    inputs_list = [x1.value,x2.value,x3.value,x4.value,x5.value,x6.value,x7.value,x8.value,x9.value,x10.value,x11.value]
    #Use the inputs_list as input to run another SW program 
    #The SW program will return an objective value j which is float value
    #The goal is to find min. objective value with corresponding x1-x11 value
    return j



m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
m.options.SOLVER=1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver

# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

# Initialize variables
# Integer constraints for x1 to x11
x1 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x2 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x3 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x4 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x5 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x6 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x7 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x8 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x9 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x10 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x11 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)

m.Obj(f_per_particle(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11)) # Objective
m.solve() # Solve

Execution result as follows :
apm 130.226.87.11_gk_model0 <br><pre> ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------


 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :           11
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            1
   Residuals    :            1

 ________________________________________________
 WARNING: objective equation           1 has no variables
 ss.Eqn(1)
 0 = 0.06
 ________________________________________________
 Number of state variables:             11
 Number of total equations: -            0
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             11

 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  6.00E-02 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.410000000032596E-002 sec
 Objective      :   6.000000000000000E-002
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

Results
x1: [8.0]
x2: [8.0]
x3: [8.0]
x4: [8.0]
x5: [8.0]
x6: [8.0]
x7: [8.0]
x8: [8.0]
x9: [8.0]
x10: [8.0]
x11: [8.0]
Objective: 0.06
(virtual-env) nan@TEK-CB-NAN-01:~/Swarm_Sandbox/GEKKO/mlp_fi_fwl/run$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete but simplified version of your problem:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
def f(x1,x2):
    return (x1.value-3.3)**2 + (x2.value-5.7)**2
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
m.options.SOLVER=1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver
x1 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x2 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
m.Obj(f(x1,x2)) # Objective
m.solve() # Solve
print('Objective: ' + str((8-3.3)**2 + (8-5.7)**2))
print(x1.value[0],x2.value[0])
```

It produces a solution, similar to yours, where the solver does not move the values from the initial guess. This is because your objective function is returning a scalar, not a Gekko expression. Gekko requires an expression so that it can perform operator overloading to provide automatic differentiation for the solvers and provide exact 1st and 2nd derivatives in sparse form. You would need to modify your code to provide a function approximation of your objective function using something like a [cspline](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectCspline) or [bspline](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline) based on sampling your objective function over a range of variables or else use a Gekko expression. Here is a modified version that uses a Gekko expression:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
def f(x1,x2):
    return (x1-3.3)**2 + (x2-5.7)**2
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
m.options.SOLVER=1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver
x1 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
x2 = m.Var(value=8,lb=1,ub=16,integer=True)
m.Obj(f(x1,x2)) # Objective
m.solve() # Solve
print(x1.value[0],x2.value[0])
```

It produces the correct solution: `x1=3.0` and `x2=6.0`.

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    4 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj:  2.05E-27 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   1.80E-01 Lowest Leaf:   2.05E-27 Gap:   1.80E-01
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  1.80E-01 Gap:  1.80E-01
Iter:     3 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  9.00E-02 Gap:  1.80E-01
Iter:     4 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    1 Obj:  4.90E-01 Gap:  1.80E-01
--Integer Solution:   1.80E-01 Lowest Leaf:   5.80E-01 Gap:  -4.00E-01
Iter:     5 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    1 Obj:  5.80E-01 Gap: -4.00E-01
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.390000000174041E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.180000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, John,                                                                           Thanks for your prompt reply with a neat example. Let me ask one thing first. Is the MILP solver not gradient-free ? Since the search space is 16^11, if I need to build the function approximation model using cspline or bspline first, how many data samplings are enough ? I'll study the  materials of cspline and bspline you provide first. For GEKKO expression, I cannot make it since I cannot model in math. Previously, I use S.A., G.A. etc. gradient-free meta-heuristic algorithm for the problem.

Comment: A side information : The objective function of the problem can only be computed by some simulations.

Comment: The APOPT solver is a gradient-based solver that uses branch and bound with an NLP solver. The search space does seem too large for a function approximation. Maybe there is another gradient-free method that would work for you. I assume that you are trying other methods because the S.A., G.A. results were not satisfactory in terms of speed or convergence?

Comment: Thank you again. Yes,  I tried S.A and G.A. but it seems the behavior of the search process is a kind of random which it's not satisfactory for me and hard to explain why. I don't see the trend of convergence in fact. The case can only evaluate the result from another simulation. I remembered you suggested I can use bpline etc. to build an approximation model first. Do you still think it's a direction for me to try? How much sampling data should I generate to construct the approximation model? You're so nice and patient with everyone who ask questions.

Comment: In your case, I think it may be best to try a gradient-free method because your objective function does not produce the required information for gradient-based methods unless those methods used finite differencing. There is a list of MINLP solvers at the bottom of the APOPT Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APOPT  I'd recommend that you look at other solvers first before trying to approximate your objective function yourself. Another solver may be able to get local approximations of the gradient.