# Optimal time gap with gekko, problem with pandas shift

Tags: pandas, gekko

I'm trying to get optimal time gap with gekko (in the example below it is 10)

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from random import random

n = 100000
arr = [random() for i in range(n)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"w1" : arr, 'w2' : arr}, \
        index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=n, freq='T'))
df.w2 = df.w2.shift(10) * 10
weight1 = df["w1"] 
weight2 = df["w2"]

model = GEKKO(remote=False)
shift = model.Var(lb=0, ub=30, integer=True)

def f(shift):
    global weight1, weight2
    print(shift.value)
    temp_weight2 = weight2.shift(periods=-shift.value, freq="T")
    return weight1.corr(temp_weight2)

model.Maximize(f(shift))
model.options.SOLVER=1
model.solve()
print(shift)
```

but i get error with shifting data frame "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()".
I guess that is because gekko gives to this function gekko object, not integer
But how to fix this?

Full error:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjWQG.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the *full* stack trace (error message), including the auto-generated code excerpts and line numbers?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler just added

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler screenshot of error is at the bottom of the post

Comment: What if you change `periods=-shift` to `periods=-int(shift.value[0])`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Then i get `"TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"`
Python can't convert gekko object to int

Comment: Hmm, then maybe just `periods=-int(shift)`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler thanks to your comment i found out, that with `periods=-shift.value` python does not throw error! But it gives wrong result (not 10)

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler from this question it sound like use x.value is not a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659995/integer-constrained-optimization-with-objective-function-expressed-to-execute-an

Answer (score 1):

An gradient-based optimizer in Gekko does not work well for this problem because (1) there are multiple local minima (non-convex) and (2) the APOPT branch and bound MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) method requires that integer variables can be temporarily evaluated at non-integer values to determine search directions.

How about a simple exhaustive search? There are only 31 evaluations of the objective function and the index of the maximum can be identified with `np.argmax()`.

[image: exhaustive search]

```py
from random import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100000
arr = [random() for i in range(n)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"w1" : arr, 'w2' : arr}, \
        index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=n, freq='T'))
df.w2 = df.w2.shift(10) * 10
weight1 = df["w1"] 
weight2 = df["w2"]

def f(shift):
    global weight1, weight2
    temp_weight2 = weight2.shift(periods=shift, freq="T")
    return weight1.corr(temp_weight2)

s = np.linspace(0,30,31).astype(int)
fs = np.array([f(si) for si in s])
fi = np.argmax(fs)
plt.plot(s,fs)
plt.plot(s[fi],fs[fi],'o')
plt.show()
```

There is more information on optimization methods from the freely available [online course](https://apmonitor.com/me575/) and [book](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/BookChapters). I recommend Chapters 5 and 6 on gradient-free optimization.